# Iterate over columns blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to loop through values of all columns and print it on table. But can't do it.  Below my controller:

```
$resultpersonel = DB::table('puantajs')
    ->leftJoin('personnels', 'puantajs.pPersonel', '=', 'personnels.id')
    ->select('personnels.sAd','personnels.sSoyad','personnels.sGorev','puantajs.*')
    ->where('puantajs.nYear', $yearresult)
    ->where('puantajs.nMonth', $monthresult)
    ->where('puantajs.pPersonel', $personel)
    ->get();
```

Below my blade code : first i get how many rows are there. second i iterate over each column and print value. This is one of the basic and standart code block. But laravel gets it so complicated.

```
@foreach($resultpersonel as  $data)

            @for ($i = 0; $i <'30'; $i++)                                               
            <td id="r">{{$data[$i]}}</td>                                                                                         
            @endfor            
            </tr>
   @endforeach
```

It gives error :

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: replace   ->get(); with ->toArray();

Comment: it gives  error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray().   if ı use both->get()->toArray() it gives  errro :Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: What's your plan with the inner loop?

Comment: just try to get column values for the row in database. I have 30 columns . I want to iterate over them inside @for loop . I want to get their values and print them on  table <table class="table table-bordered">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the elements of an object by a numeric index. You have to cast the model to an array and use a foreach:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    @foreach ($resultpersonel as $data)
        <tr>
            @foreach ($data->toArray() as $column => $value)
                <td>{{ $column }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you . I accepted this answer because it solved my question. But on my actual case I need to select specific columns . Not all columns. More specifically don't wanna select first 3 columns and last 4 columns.  How can i do that ?

Comment: There's two ways really if you want to do that the dynamic way by iterating throgh the keys of the object. You can either use Laravels [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable and check if the current index (`$loop->index`) includes the column you desire or, as you already maually select the columns, modify the columns in your `select()` method.